# using an NSArray in a custom class isn't working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Starting over.  I am fairly new to objective C.  I have created the following class and I can't figure out how to initialize the array.

Can anyone provide any guidance on how to initialize the NSArray?

StatusPost.m

```
#import "StatusPost.h"


@implementation StatusPost

@synthesize messageId, fromName, friendId, message, choice2, choice3, choice4, picture,     fbImage, commentCount, commentArray;

-(id)initWithMessageId:(NSString*) rMessageId 
       fromName:(NSString*) rFromName
         friendId:(NSString*) rFriendId
        message:(NSString*) rMessage 
           choice2:(NSString*) rChoice2
           choice3:(NSString*) rChoice3
           choice4:(NSString*) rChoice4
           picture:(NSString *) rPicture
           fbImage:(UIImage *)rfbImage
      commentCount:(NSString*) rCommentCount
      commentArray:(NSArray*) rCommentArray
{
if (self = [super init]) {
    commentArray = [NSArray new];
    self.messageId = rMessageId;
    self.fromName = rFromName;
    self.friendId = rFriendId;
    self.message = rMessage;
    self.choice2 = rChoice2;
    self.choice3 = rChoice3;
    self.choice4 = rChoice4;
    self.picture = rPicture;
    self.fbImage = rfbImage;
    self.commentCount = rCommentCount;
    self.commentArray = rCommentArray;

}
return self;
}



- (void)dealloc {
[messageId release];
[fromName release];
[friendId release];
[message release];
[picture release];
[fbImage release];
[commentCount release];
[commentArray release];
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

StatusPost.h:
    #import

```
@interface StatusPost : NSObject {
NSString* messageId;
NSString* fromName;
NSString* friendId;
NSString* message;
NSString* choice2;
NSString* choice3;
NSString* choice4;
NSString* picture;
UIImage* fbImage;
NSString* commentCount;
NSArray* commentArray;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* messageId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* fromName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* friendId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* message;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* choice2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* choice3;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* choice4;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* picture;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage* fbImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* commentCount;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* commentArray;


-(id)initWithMessageId:(NSString*) rMessageId 
       fromName:(NSString*) rFromName
         friendId:(NSString*) rFriendId
        message:(NSString*) rMessage
           choice2:(NSString*) rChoice2
           choice3:(NSString*) rChoice3
           choice4:(NSString*) rChoice4
           picture:(NSString*) rPicture
           fbImage:(UIImage*) rfbImage
      commentCount:(NSString*) rCommentCount
      commentArray:(NSArray*) rCommentArray;

@end
```

Comment: How did you initialize the array. Please add more code so we can know what's going on.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying. Can you elaborate?

Comment: What is rCommentArray?  You first create an empty array with the new command and assign that to the ivar commentArray, and then reassign commentArray to rCommentArray.  Also, you're using self.commentArray, which can only be used for properties, did you create a property? I only see an ivar declaration in your posted code.

Comment: I posted my complete class because I do not really understand how to initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you aren't ever initializing the array, so when you try to add an object, you are just sending a message to nil. In the custom class's `init` method, add the line:

```
commentArray = [NSMutableArray new];
```

Comment: I added the line in the class but same results.  I posted the code above

Comment: um you initialised it, then promptly assigned a value over the top of that initialisation ...  how is rCommentArray being initialised ??  The initialisation you added will have no effect due to you assigning rComment array to the same attribute a few lines later.

Comment: I posted my complete class because I do not really understand how to initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

`[NSArray new]` is shorthand for `[[NSArray alloc] init]`, so, technically speaking, that statement "inits" the NSArray.

However, your code looks a bit peculiar.  You have the following statements in your `init`:

```
commentArray = [NSArray new];
self.commentArray = rCommentArray;
```

The first statement is setting the instance variable `commentArray` to the address of the newly alloced/inited NSArray while the second is setting the property `commentArray` to a parameter value.  However, you have (through the `@synthesize`) made the instance variable `commentArray` the "backing store" for the property `commentArray`, so when you execute the second line the effect of the first line is overwritten (and the NSArray you created is "leaked").

(But if your real question is how to "load" an NSArray with values, you should ask that question -- and you'll get different answers.)